# SCons to make a shared library (.so) with a static library (.a)

Tags: static, static-libraries, portability, static-linking, scons

I'm trying to get SCons to make a shared library. One of the items going into the `.so` is a `.a` static lib.

I have a line like:

```
env_2.SharedLibrary('libstuff.so', \
  Split("""stuff.cxx mylib/libMine.a""")
```

And upon running it, I get this error:

```
scons: *** Source file: mylib/libMine.a \
is static and is not compatible with shared target: libstuff.so
```

However, I know that a shared library can be made from the `.a` via a command like:

```
g++ -m32 -shared -o libstuff.so stuff.o mylib/libMine.a
```

Any ideas on getting this to work or any workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

---

Related question: How do I get scons to put an additional string `-shared` on the LINK command line for the `Program()` call? If I could do this, I think it would meet my needs.

Answer (score 13):

Try to set `env['STATIC_AND_SHARED_OBJECTS_ARE_THE_SAME']=1` in your SConstruct.

Comment: This 'magic voodoo' worked for me as well.  I am surprised because I did not see any difference in the compile command options after adding the to the SConstruct.  I hope the witch doctor that came up with this magic explains it to us mortals.

Comment: The SharedLibrary builder checks if all given object files were built with the SharedObject builder (and thus with -fPIC). env['STATIC_AND_SHARED_OBJECTS_ARE_THE_SAME']=1 disables this check. You need to decide yourself if this is actually a good idea...

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not specific to scons. To build a shared library, you'll need objects that are compiled with position independent code (`-fPIC`). Your best bet is to make the shared library out of the source files compiled with the right options.

In SCons, you can define a list of targets that's used to build both libMine.a and libShared.so.

---

**Update**: for your second question, the [SharedLibrary](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/c593.html#AEN641) builder might do what you need:

```
SharedLibrary('foo', ['f1.c', 'f2.c', 'f3.c'])
```

If not, `LINKFLAGS` sets the flags passed to a link command.

Comment: I think you are right that the .a has .o files NOT made using -fPIC.  However the g++ -m32 -shared .... still works somehow.

Comment: I went back and had the files going into the .a be compiled with -fPIC, but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
env_2.SharedLibrary('libstuff.so', Split("""stuff.cxx"""), LIBS='libMine.a', LIBPATH='mylib')
```

This should work.

Comment: @shoosh Yes, it does.  The `SharedLibrary` builder uses `ProgramScanner` to search for dependencies specified via `LIBS`.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem under cygwin. I passed '-fPIC' options to gcc when building the objects and got the following warning:

> warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)

I also passed '-shared' to the link command. And I finally got the error

> "***.lib is static and is not compatible with shared target: myso.dll"

It seems scons doesn't allow to create so directly from obj or lib files, and one can either create the so from a list of sources files (using SharedLibrary()) or source file + 'LIBS' option like dummytaurus says. I'm curious about that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the function `SharedFlagChecker` (Default.py), which checks only for an internal "shared" flag. The SCons documentation leads you to believe that it keeps the distinction between shared objects and static objects via the suffix (`SHOBJSUFFIX`), but not so. The fix is easy. In the file `scons-local.../SCons/Default.py` find the `SharedFlagChecker`and edit:

```py
def SharedFlagChecker(source, target, env):
    same = env.subst('$STATIC_AND_SHARED_OBJECTS_ARE_THE_SAME')
    if same == '0' or same == '' or same == 'False':
        for src in source:
            try:
                shared = src.attributes.shared
            except AttributeError:
                # Replace this line: shared = None
                shared = env.Dictionary()['SHOBJSUFFIX'] == src.suffix
            if not shared:
                raise SCons.Errors.UserError("Source file: ...")
```

Now objects made via the `SharedObject` builder will be linkable in a shared library.

Comment: You should use env['STATIC_AND_SHARED_OBJECTS_ARE_THE_SAME']=True and not hack the code to disable this.. It's in the manpage.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to resolve this issue have been used a 'SharedObject' as the following:

```
ASN1CObjectFile = envCProcesses.SharedObject(target = "OTCMsg.os",
                                             source = "OTCMsg.c",
                                             CFLAGS = envCProcesses["CFLAGS"] + ["-Wno-unused"])
```

and:

```
OTCLibSharedLibrary = envCProcesses.SharedLibrary(env["OTC_LIBPATH"] + "/libOTCLib" + env["SHLIBSUFFIX"],
                                              ASN1CObjectFile +
                                              [ASN1AllocatorSource,
                                               "OTCLib.c"],
                                              LIBPREFIX = "")
```

Best regards,

Comment: env["OTC_LIBPATH"] + "/libOTCLib" + env["SHLIBSUFFIX"] could be rewritten as "${OTC_LIBPATH}/libOTCLib$SHLIBSUFFIX"